# Input using a submit button in Jupyter notebook using widget

Tags: widget, jupyter-notebook, ipython

How can I take input using a submit button in notebook?

I want to display an input drop down selector and store the input only when the user hits the submit button.

Something like this -

[image: Sample Image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the value of the selection in the button click action.
This involves several steps in any approach.  If you used `jp_proxy_widget`
it might look like this:

[image]

see: https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_proxy_widget

and https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/